# Fixed length loop in Python?

Tags: python

I have googled on how to write a fixed length loop in Python but haven't found anything, so I ask here:

```
    for i in range(0, 25):
        index = int(random.uniform(0, len(characters)))
        code += characters[index]
    return code
```

As you see I don't need `i`. How can I rewrite this to be a fixed length loop where I don't have to define `i`?

Answer (score 2):

```
for _ in range(25):
    index = int(random.uniform(0, len(characters)))
    code += characters[index]
return code
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, no unnecessary variable required:

```
it = iter(range(25))
while True:
    try:
        next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    # do stuff
    pass
```

Of course, that introduces an ugly *necessary* variable, and basically re-implements the python iterator-based for-loop using a while-loop, but that is an option.

Most people would go for the idiomatic for-loop, and maybe use the conventional throw-away variable, the underscore:

```
for _ in range(25):
    # do stuff
    pass
```